# How to plot two `ggscatter` correlation plots with confidence intervals on the same graph in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am trying to get a spearman correlation for two scatter plots with confidence intervals on the same graph but it is proving difficult to do.

Given the following data:

```
spentWithTool <- sample(1:7, 20, replace = TRUE)
understoodWithTool <- sample(1:5, 20, replace = TRUE)
spentWithoutTool <- sample(1:4, 10, replace = TRUE)
understoodWithoutTool <- sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)
```

This is the best workaround I came up with but it is not what I want - I want the withTool and the withoutTool plots to be on the same graph and NOT side by side.

```
plot_with <- ggscatter(data = data.frame(spentWithTool, understoodWithTool),
                     x = 'spentWithTool',
                     y = 'understoodWithTool',
                     color = 'darkred',
                     cor.method = "spearman",
                     cor.coef = TRUE,
                     conf.int = TRUE,
                     add = "reg.line",
                     add.params = list(color = 'red'),
                    )
plot_without <- ggscatter(data = data.frame(spentWithoutTool, understoodWithoutTool),
                      x = 'spentWithoutTool',
                      y = 'understoodWithoutTool',
                      color = 'darkblue',
                      cor.method = "spearman",
                      cor.coef = TRUE,
                      conf.int = TRUE,
                      add = "reg.line",
                      add.params = list(color = 'blue')
ggarrange(plotlist = list(plot_with, plot_without))
```

The above gives me:
[image]

Using `ggpar(p = list(plot_with, plot_without))` just created two separate graphs so it was not helpful.

I am trying to get two lines (red and blue), where each line represents withTool and withoutTool respectively and the x and y axis represent timeSpent and understood respectively. Ideally, the confidence intervals, would be the same colour as what the line represents (red for withTool and blue for withoutTool).

Is there a way to get both correlation lines and points on the same graph?

Aside - Is there a way to use `ggscatter` without creating a data frame from vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking out the docs and trying several options using the `color` and `ggp` arguments of `ggscatter` IMHO the easiest and less time-consuming option to achieve your desired result would be to build your plot from scratch using `ggplot2` with some support from `ggpubr` to add the regression equations and the theme:

```r
set.seed(1)

spentWithTool <- sample(1:7, 20, replace = TRUE)
understoodWithTool <- sample(1:5, 20, replace = TRUE)
spentWithoutTool <- sample(1:4, 10, replace = TRUE)
understoodWithoutTool <- sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

df <- rbind.data.frame(
  data.frame(x = spentWithTool, y = understoodWithTool, id = "with"),
  data.frame(x = spentWithoutTool, y = understoodWithoutTool, id = "without")
  
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = id, fill = id)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  stat_cor(method = "spearman") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(with = "red", without = "blue"), aesthetics = c("color", "fill")) +
  theme_pubr() +
  labs(x = "timeSpent", y = "understood")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there no way to add the "spearman" correlation with the p-value to this?

Comment: Haha. Sorry. My fault. See my edit. Simply use `stat_cor(method = "spearman")` instead of `stat_regline_equation`.